# Change all elements in a list of indices corresponding to another list

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists:

```
b = ['zero', 'one', 'two']
c = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0]
```

Is there an elegant way to change every element in `c` and get

```
c = ['zero', 'zero', 'zero', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'zero', 'two', 'zero']
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think just

```
c = [b[i] for i in c]
```

would do the trick

Answer (score 5):

```py
c = map(lambda i: b[i],c)
```

Using map

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

itemgetter(*c)(b)
```

Output:

```
('zero', 'zero', 'zero', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'zero', 'two', 'zero')
```